# An example to show that convergence of Cesaro sum to $0$ does not imply the original sequence converges to $0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, examples-counterexamples

I'd like construct a non-negative sequence $\{a_{k}\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ with $a_{0}=0$ such that the Cesaro sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}\longrightarrow 0$ but $a_{n}$ does not converge to $0$.

I have a really bad attempt:

Define $a_{0}=a_{1}=0$, and $a_{k}:=\log(\log(k))$ for $k\geq 2$, then $a_{k}\longrightarrow\infty$. But $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}=\dfrac{\log\Big(\prod_{k=2}^{n-1}\log(k)\Big)}{n}$$ and Wolframalpha told me that this series converges to $0$ as $n\longrightarrow\infty$.

However, I have no idea about how to show this convergence to $0$. Also, I wish to have a sequence as simple as possible, since at some stage I need too how $f(k):=a_{k}$ is positive semi-definite.

Is there any simpler example?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the problem to construct a sequence $a_n$ and show it has the required property, or is the problem to show that the particular sequence mentioned in the post has the required property?

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard this is a problem to construct a sequence $a_{n}$ and show it has the required property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $a_k=(-1)^k$ C-sum $\to 0$, but $a_k$ does not converge.

Comment: +1 nice simple example

Comment: Oh I am sorry I need the sequence to be non-negative. Let me edit this question.

Comment: Change $a_k=1+(-1)^k$. C-sum $\to 1$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg but I need the $C-$sum$\longrightarrow 0$...

Comment: For $k=2^m$, ($m$ an integer), let $a_k=1$. Otherwise $a_k=0$. C-sum $\to 0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg would you mind proving this statement? I tried to write out a formula for the summation but failed..

Comment: : To be specific:  $2^m\le n\lt 2^{m+1}$, C-sum =$\frac{m}{n}\to 0$.

Comment: To see it more clearly, note that $m\le log_2(n)$ in previous note.

Answer (score 2):

Try $$a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{$n$ is a power of $2$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I am sorry that I did not figure out the formula for the sum...